# Benefits of leveling a Guild

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

I have created a Guild with 2 of my friends.  It seems like for smaller guilds, there is almost no way to level the guild.  Since the requirement for the first level up is 2 million exp, it makes it impossible to level.  Should we even donate any exp to the guild?  Does it only make sense to donate exp at max level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guild earns Exp through taxes for Exp gained from killing monsters, but not for quests.

[Apparently, when a player gains a level-up, the guild will receive 1% of the Exp the player had needed to reach that level](http://forums.warpportal.com/index.php?/topic/116493-guild-experience/page__hl__%2Bguild+%2Bexperience__fromsearch__1) (although it is not known to me, if this happens only for guild members that are donating Exp, or if it happens for every guild member)

Generally, it would appear that taxation only makes sense at max level.